# ansible-playbook with group_vars

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to organize ansible from a ssh model to pull. Before I had a setup like

```
group_vars/
  all
  prod
  stage
  dev
```

Now I'm trying to run everything via cron so I tried this setup

```
staging/
   inventory
   group_vars/
      server
prod/
   inventory
   group_vars/
      server
```

inventory on both look like

```
[server]
localhost   ansible_connection=local
```

for stage my group_vars look like

```
---
rails_env: staging
```

I have an example play

```
- hosts: server
  user: root
  sudo: no
  gather_facts: True

  tasks:
     - debug: msg="reading from {{ rails_env }}"
```

My run output is

```
# ansible-playbook -i staging test.yml

PLAY [server] *****************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [debug msg="reading from {{ rails_env }}"] ******************************
fatal: [localhost] => One or more undefined variables: 'rails_env' is undefined

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/root/test.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong as it should pick that up

Comment: You're running with `-i staging`, but I your inventory file is actually called `inventory`...

Comment: thanks that was the issue.. I must of read it wrong where i thought inventory was auto searched in the directory.

Comment: No, really, it should work as you initially wanted. I'm not sure about older versions, but 2.1.0 certainly does read `inventory` file if `-i` points to a directory containing it.

Comment: ok I'm still using 1.9

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.9 you can't do that, on stable version 2.0.2.0 doesn't work either. 
You should read this: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html .
I suggest running like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i staging/inventory test.yml
```